# How to find whether a substring is included in a list?

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset (df) of news that looks more or less like this:

```
# v1     v2       subjects                                  body
# 1997   EMER   : ["N2:LEN", "N2:RTRS", "R:XON.N"],        "blablabla"
# 1998   EMER   : ["R:AAPL.N", "N2:MD", "N2:H"],           "blabla"
# 1998   AMEA   : ["N2:E", "N2:MD", "R:AA.T"],             "blabla2"
```

(It is not very clean, thus the ": [" in the subjects column).

Then I have a list of subjects (tags) which actually includes around 70 thousands elements:

```
# tags
# R:0#CRX*.A
# R:0#HMO*.A
# R:AA.N
# R:AAPL.N
# R:XON.N
# R:DELL.N
```

I want to keep only the rows of df where df$subjects include at least one of the elements in tags (thus, in this example, I want to keep only the first two rows of df). Expected output:

```
# v1     v2       subjects                                  body
# 1997   EMER   : ["N2:LEN", "N2:RTRS", "R:XON.N"],        "blablabla"
# 1998   EMER   : ["R:AAPL.N", "N2:MD", "N2:H"],           "blabla"
```

I tried with grepl:

```
tags_collapsed=paste(tags,collapse = "|")
tags_collapsed=gsub("[[:space:]]", "", tags_collapsed)

df=df[grepl(tags_collapsed,df$subjects),]
```

but it gives me the following error:

> Error in grepl(tags_collapsed, df$subjects) : 
>   invalid regular expression 
>   'R:0#CRX*.A|R:0#HMO*.A|R:AA.N|R:AAPL.N|...

without giving more details. I also tried excluding the tags with special characters (e.g. without R:0#CRX*.A|R:0#HMO*.A) and it gives the same error.

Instead, I tried applying grepl on df using, as pattern, only two tags, and it worked.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

**Data.**

```
df <-
structure(list(v1 = c(1997L, 1998L, 1998L), v2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("   AMEA", "   EMER"), class = "factor"), 
subjects = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("   : [N2:E, N2:MD, R:AA.T]", 
"   : [N2:LEN, N2:RTRS, R:XON.N]", "   : [R:AAPL.N, N2:MD, N2:H]"),
class = "factor"), body = structure(3:1, .Label = c("             blabla2", 
    "           blabla", "        blablabla"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

tags <- scan(what = character(), text = '
R:0#CRX*.A
R:0#HMO*.A
R:AA.N
R:AAPL.N
R:XON.N
R:DELL.N
')
```

Comment: Hmm weird, I tried using the data + code you posted here, and it ran just fine. Edit: a [reprex](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219) might be helpful?

Comment: Can you do ```dput(head(df))``` and edit your question to include the results of that to give the first few lines of your actual dataframe that others can use to read in easily? Also, if you can provide more detail around your expected output that will get your question more attention.

Comment: Your `grep(tags_collapsed, df$subjects)` works with me.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Excellent solution!

Comment: @Dunois, yes with few tags it works, the problem is that it does not work with my actual 70 thousands tags. Thus it could be that the problem is the length of pattern, even though the error message does not explicitly say so. Any advice for this problem?

Comment: @Rui Barradas, same as previous comment.

Comment: @Russ Thomas, ok thanks for the suggestion, will do that.

Comment: @Esperanta, you could store the tags as a list and loop through them?

Comment: @Esperanta, can you do some experimentation and see where it breaks down?  May be a bug in the regexp-handling code (which is probably *not* written by R-core, but imported from an existing software library ...).  (Even if the "squash all the tags together in one big regex" strategy can be made to work, someone may come up with a more efficient solution ...) If you have access to GNU tools, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632244/regex-to-detect-one-of-several-strings) suggests that GNU `fgrep` may be more efficient

Comment: PS if you do find that there's some limit to the length of a regex (say 1024 chars or something), you can combine this with @Dunois's idea: block your tags in groups small enough to stay within limits, then loop over those groups

Comment: PPS searching the error message gives this explanation and workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769816/is-there-a-limit-to-the-string-length-that-can-be-passed-to-grep-in-r

Comment: I would close as a duplicate, except that `fgrep` might be a better solution in this case.

Comment: @BenBolker by adding in the code `perl=T`, the lenght limit is around 3650 elements in the tags list, so I am splitting the list in smaller lists.

Answer (score 1):

The long pattern *vector* problem can be solved with a `lapply` loop. The long *string* problem seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the 70K patterns were replaced by a huge string after `paste/collapse`, which in turn caused `grep` to malfunction.

The code below uses `lapply` to search the patterns. Then, it keeps only the unique, sorted indices into `df$subject`.

```
i <- lapply(tags, grep, df$subjects)
i <- sort(unique(unlist(i)))
df[i, ]
#    v1      v2                        subjects              body
#1 1997    EMER    : [N2:LEN, N2:RTRS, R:XON.N]         blablabla
#2 1998    EMER       : [R:AAPL.N, N2:MD, N2:H]            blabla
```

Now for a test with a 70K patterns vector. The original patterns are extended with a letter, enough to have no matches. So I include `tags` and shuffle with `sample`. Then the code above repeats.

```
set.seed(1234)
tags2 <- paste(tags, sample(letters, 70e3, TRUE), sep = ".")
tags2 <- sample(c(tags, tags2))
length(tags2)
#[1] 70006

j <- lapply(tags2, grep, df$subjects)
j <- sort(unique(unlist(j)))
df[j, ]
#    v1      v2                        subjects              body
#1 1997    EMER    : [N2:LEN, N2:RTRS, R:XON.N]         blablabla
#2 1998    EMER       : [R:AAPL.N, N2:MD, N2:H]            blabla
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it gives me the same error as before. I guess the problem is the lenght of the pattern: my actual list contains precisely 74614 elements, and maybe many are longer than yours, I don't know. I split the tags list in lists with 3500 elements, and then ran ` df=df[grepl(tags_collapsed,dft$subjects,perl = T),] ` for every shorter list and it works, even though maybe it's not very efficient.